# Android + Espresso + async HTTP request -> how to test?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

i'm trying to test Android app using Espresso FW and I stucked on the problem with doing async HTTP request.

How can i test the case that app (activity) is waiting for processing request and after the response is received is displayed next activity with result or error message?

I tried to find any solution how to do it in the Espresso with testing against the data from the test server, but without luck.

Many thanks for any advice, example or link.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a few days. If your app is using retrofit to handle HTTP requests, you can add this one line:

```
.setExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new MainThreadExecutor())
```

to your RestAdaptor.Builder. This moves all of the HTTP requests into the AsyncTasks pool which is then handled by espresso.

I found the original answer here: http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2015/08/03/using-espresso-for-easy-ui-testing/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in app architecture. 
You should use some Dependency Injection library to inject mock service with mock data in your application in test mode. 
When you inject "test" implementation ( mocks)  when you testing. U will avoid problems with not network availability or you can simulate network availability by your test implementation.

Comment: Can you provide any example of this? I would like to test on real server data, but if it is not possible i will use some mock data.

Comment: @mariopce: can you help me in this. how to setup this. is there any libraries for this? i am stucked in this. please help me.

Comment: I don't accept this. While you should probably _also_ test using mocks as you describe, there are valid reasons for testing against a live service.